# mvc custom route gives 404

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am trying to make a custom route but I cannot get it working and even though everything seems okay it always returns 404.

So here are the route defined.

It is defined first before the default and according to route debugger this is the route that gets hit.`(Matched Route: Game/{id}/{title})`

```
routes.Add(
    "GamesDefault",
    new Route("Game/{id}/{title}",
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Games", action = "ShowGame" }),
    new DefaultMvcRouteHandler(urlTranslator, urlFoundAction)));
```

Here is the path Im trying to reach: `/Game/5/test`

And this is the Controller declaration. The `GamesController` is placed in the Controllers folder and its view are in `Views/Games/showGames.cshtml`.

```
public GamesController()
{
}

public ActionResult ShowGames(int id, string title)
{
    return View(title);
}
```

The DefaultMvcRouteHandler doesnt do anything fancy.

```
public class DefaultMvcRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

The default route works without problems, and I have tried everything I can find like changing the name of the route so it doesnt match any folders or anything like that.
If anyone have any ideas on what more to try I would be most grateful.

Comment: You are passing default route values of "Games" and "ShowGame" but your controller is called "GamesController" the action method is called "ShowGames".

Comment: omg, I knew it was something like that but I just couldnt find it, have been at this for hours now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment you are passing incorrect default route values for the `controller` and `action` values.

Update your route like so:

```
routes.Add(
   "GamesDefault",
   new Route("Game/{id}/{title}",
   new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "GamesController", action = "ShowGames" }),
   new DefaultMvcRouteHandler(urlTranslator, urlFoundAction)));
```